How do I disable Internet access on my MacBook as to make it IMPOSSIBLE to re-enable it?
I need to automatically disable internet access on my MacBook after 11:00 PM daily. To re-enable it, a password must be entered, distinct from sudo, known only to a trusted individual (so i need to call them, and ask for password, if something urgent happened). Internet access should automatically resume after 4:00 AM.
IMPORTANT! - Access cannot be restored using sudo alone.
Something like multisig wallet in crypto.
I need it for myself, because I want sleep good, without using pc.
Thank you.

Get the self control app.

https://selfcontrolapp.com/

Warning, if you set the timer too long, it’s very unlikely you can get access back. Also, I would get some help from a friend or counselor if you use sudo when you know you shouldn’t. Addiction is nothing to be ashamed of and you can improve all the other areas of your life in addition to networking during rest periods by taking a look at the source of the problem instead of treating a symptom.
Temporary treatments can be powerful, I hope the recommendation helps you carve out the part of the network you need to resist while you work on the big picture with some rest.

thank you, good solution, but unfortunately it will not work automatically, as I understand

The only long-lasting remedy is to take control of  yourself, not the technology.  There’s no shame in seeking professional help to confront your addiction. Sometimes taking that first step to seek help can be liberating. You’ve recognized there is a problem. You can do this.

Have you tried it @DREVMYSOUL - If you can manually enable the filter, you can ask here how to automate things on a timer. There may be several avenues if the tool otherwise works. Routers also often have time limits like this - would that be an option?
